# How to delete the unique row and keep the duplicate values in the data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a huge dataset that contains patient_details. I want to delete the unique (ID) rows and keep the ID's which repeat more than once(duplicates).
I'm not familiar with python. Kindly Help me to solve it in Spyder-Python.

```
ID   Date      val1 val2
101 12/11/2000   15   18
108 06/06/1998   23   54
108 07/07/1992   85   98
103 01/02/2001   45   65
```

Expected result as

```
ID   Date      val1 val2
108 06/06/1998   23   54
108 07/07/1992   85   98
```

Comment: Something like: `new_df = df[df['ID'].duplicated(keep=False)]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checks if the `ID` is duplicated, if it is true, then it keeps it.

```
df = df[df['ID'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Comment: Thank you all it works well. How do I know to make sure those unique data are deleted. i.e How could I view the no.of rows of data?

Comment: just updated the code

Comment: ```len(df)``` shows the number of rows